# find command regex with optional subexpression

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have the following file list

```
file                        <-
file.2019041543764832       <-
file.2019041643764832       <-
file.2019041243764832
file.2019041143764832
```

I want to find all the marked files which are prefixed with `file` and optionally suffixed by the dates `20190415xxxxx` or `20190416xxxxx`

I have tried the following but it does not yield any output.

`find . -regex 'file(\.2019041(5|6)[0-9].*)?' -regextype egrep`

I need some help with the correct regex type and the correct synatx to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -regex './file\(.2019041\(5\|6\)[0-9]*\)?' -regextype egrep
```

or just

```
find . -regex './file\(.2019041[56][0-9]*\)?'
```

(When using `find .`, my version of `find` prefixes the matches with `./`, so I added that to the regexp.)

Comment: I guess I was missing the `\` to escape the characters. thanks! is there anyway to do it without all of this escaping?